# No Sign of Applet Running from HTML

Tags: java, applet

I put together a java ChatClient and ChatServer on Max OS X Version 10.7.5 for fun with my kids. We were using Java Version `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b21)`. It runs great from the Terminal. Also, we'd like to able to run it from Eclipse by passing in parameters.

When I open the HTML in Safari 6.0.2., I get no sign of errors or the applet running. In Safari, I have enable plug-ins, Java, and Javascript. Only the text in the HTML is displayed; the applet does not seem to run or anything.

Once I get this working, I would like to package in a JAR file and sign it so I can create a socket to my server. The applet is a simple guy that asks to connect via socket, then sends and receives text from any other clients including itself.

```
<Html>
    <Head>
        <Title>Java Example</Title>
    </Head>

    <Body>
        This is my page<br>
        Below you see an applet<br>
        <br>
        <Applet Code="ChatClient" width=200 Height=100>
            <PARAM name="host" value="xxxxx-iMac.local">
            <PARAM name="port" value="4445">
        </Applet>
        after Applet
    </Body>
</Html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In section 13.4, the APPLET tag in HTML is deprecated, and it's successor is the `<object>` element.  You should think about a couple things here -

First, abide by HTML standards.  This includes having all of your html tags and attributes in lowercase.  `<PascalCase>`, `<camelCase>` are not standard for HTML.

Second, switch your applet tag to an object.

Thirdly, wrap all text in a block tag other than `<body>`. Most popular one is `<p>` meaning paragraph.

Fourthly, wrap ALL html attribute values in double quotes. example: `width=200` should be `width="200"`

Fifthly, think about doing 2 spaced tabs when doing html. it's much cleaner :)

I could go on, but i could be here forever.  Bottom line is, **follow standards**.

**But to answer your question:**
In the specification, it looks like it expects the file name.  this includes ".class" at the end. Try,

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Java Applet Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <applet code="ChatClient.class" width="200" height="100">
        <param name="host" value="xxxxx-iMac.local" />
        <param name="port" value="4445" />
      </applet>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And i just noticed the file gets locked even when i exit browser as well as reboot. Any help appreciated.

Comment: did adding "ChatClient.class" instead of just "ChatClient" work?

Comment: Thanks. Tried that Earlier and same results.

Comment: I tried the above html and the same results. I also replaced ChatClient.class with an example of HelloWorld.class. Same results. Just displays a blank screen as off the applet is not being invoked. Any other ideas. Thank You.

Comment: I just upgraded java plugin. Also, went into java control panel on mac and set security to lowest setting of medium. Applet now runs. Thank you for the assistance. Now my applet does not appear to have privilege to create socket. I will evaluate this and if cant fix, i will post another question. Guess since applet i may need to package as jar file and sign, but will see. Thanks Again.